# What are websites or applications for practicing performance testing from home

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, apm

I want to practice performance testing at home using some load testing tool like jmeter. Can anybody tell me some links of websites or applications on which I can practice performance testing by throwing load by load testing tool from home?

Comment: Please be aware that practicing doing performance testing on someone else's website without their express permission is not just anti social but your test may be seen as a denial of service attack upon their website.

Comment: He is asking for sites that grant permission. So it's fine! You may use http://api.jmeter.ninja/example.html see details below.

Comment: You could also use http://blazedemo.com.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a `LEGAL` way to conduct load/stress test on any live websites/web applications without the permission.

So, you can deploy your own sample application or download sample applications available online and deploy it in your local server like Apache HTTP server or Apache Tomcat etc.

From my knowledge, You can use `WebTours` sample application from HP LoadRunner as an application to put your load.

1. Download HP Load Runner community edition from [here](http://www8.hp.com/in/en/software-solutions/loadrunner-load-testing/). `free for 50 vusers` for `life time`. You need to create an account in the website.
2. You can download the webtours application from the HP website (comes with Apache HTTP server, which acts as a Web server).
3. Setup WebTours as per the instructions [here](http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/help/WebHelp/Content/Tutorial/WebTours.htm)
4. Confirm the successful installation/configuration by accessing the application from the browser (similar to http://localhost:8080/WebTours). The app is about `flight booking` (though not in real time ;) ).
5. Now, you can use the WebTours application as an AUT (Application Under Test)
6. Either you can continue with Load Runner or download latest JMeter version (3.1 as of now)

**JMeter tutorials:**

1. [Getting Started](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)
2. [Component Reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html)
3. [Builiding a Test plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-test-plan.html)

For Load Runner, there is documentation available in the following link to start with:

1. http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/help/WebHelp/Content/WelcomeContent/c_Welcome.htm

There is community support available managed by HP.

Answer (score 2):

- Use the sample applications which ship with the tool
- Take your choice of open source application, install them on servers you own, manage and control.  Use these applications as targets.

Comment: Actually i will do performance testing on my laptop. If i use open source application  on server installed on the same laptop from which i will be doing performance testing, then will i be able to learn network related monitoring and tuning?

Comment: If your goal is to test networks then learn a network test tool.  I recommend IXChariot as a great tool in such a case

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to use api.jmeter.ninja. I built it for that purpose. A more formal API declaration is on it''s way but you can start with

```
http://api.jmeter.ninja/example.html.

http://api.jmeter.ninja/objects.xml
http://api.jmeter.ninja/objects/${OBJECT}.XML
Where ${OBJECT} is taken from the objects.xml page.
```

Or swap  xml for dot json for the same in Jason format.

Exercises/Tutorial is available at http://api.jmeter.ninja/jmeter.pdf

Currently I just use this service for my own training sessions. But I hope to make it more generally available in the near future. There a currently no automatic limits so please just use your common sense and don't run high at throughput for a sustained periods of time. Anything under a total 100k requests is no problem.

Only caveat is that service is provided on a best effort basis at this point. Any abusive/problematic users may be blocked without notice.